# How to implement all files which have no extension with asterisk?

Tags: makefile, gitignore

Is there some way to implement all files with no extension using asterisk? I want to use it in *Makefile* or *.gitignore* implementation to remove or ignore all non-extension files such as *README*, *Makefile* and complied *C* file. When I use just `rm *` format, it delete ALL files regardless of extension, while I want to control ONLY non-extension files.

Comment: *"using asterisk"* Is it in gitignore or in the shell? Please choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that a file name with *no extension* means *without a dot*.

In a `.gitignore` file you can include again (with `!pattern`) files that have been excluded by a previous pattern. So:

```
*
!*.*
```

should ignore all files (or directories) without extension.

In a `Makefile` you can use functions or macros provided by your version of make (which you forgot to indicate). Example if you use GNU make with `wildcard` and `filter-out`:

```
ALL := $(wildcard *)
WITH_EXTENSION := $(wildcard *.*)
WITHOUT_EXTENSION := $(filter-out $(WITH_EXTENSION),$(ALL))

.PHONY: test
test:
    @echo $(WITHOUT_EXTENSION)
```

Note: it would have been be better to ask two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore certain files while remove then you can put them in not `!` condition.
Please see below example: 
If you want to remove all files except 'README' file then you can use find command in below way:

```
find . -type f ! -name 'README' -delete
```

The above is just an example to show how you can ignore certain files.